# Measure the main thread's load factor in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my video player style application, I have a bunch of things that are updated while the playback is running.

There is the video itself (drawn onto a NSOpenGLLayer set to asynchronous), there are several counters (NSTextFields, updated up to 30 times per second), Core Animation powered audio meters, a playhead bar, a blinking button (changing the image once per second) and some other minor things.

While it works flawlessly on my machines, I heard of folks reporting stuttering playback and stalled UI elements. Thus, I think that I managed to completely overload the UI thread.

From what I found out so far, updating the textfield's stringValue seems to be a rather heavy task. Esp. when changing it a couple of times per second.

Currently, I'm setting up a CVDisplayLink for each UI element that needs to update itself during playback. I know that this is not ideal and I also tried to create a common display link which didn't seem to make much difference.

Is there any way to measure what happens on the main thread and what takes the most time?

Any other hints to find and fix what happens here are very welcome as well!

Comment: I don't know personally, but I watched this talk at this year's WWDC that sounds like it may be useful for you.  https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=412.  "Profiling In Depth."  Maybe that can help you out?

Comment: Thanks @MattyAyOh! Will watch that and see if it helps.